# Make each button manipulate the content above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was practising with jQuery when I faced this obstacle.

I created 10 `article` tags with content inside each one. I wrote a function to automatically add an `id` for each `article` tag (`id+1`, `id+2`, etc.) and then I created a `button` tag after each `article` tag using JavaScript as well.

I cannot figure out the code that makes the first button manipulate *article 1*'s tag, for example. I want each button to solely affect the article above it. How can I achieve this logically?

Here is my code:

```js
$(function () {
    // Script begin ----
    
    const $articles = $(".siblings");
    
    const articlesManipulator = (function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < $articles.length; i++) {
            $articles[i].id = "sibling-" + (i+1);
            let $btn = document.createElement("button");
            $btn.textContent = "play with me :)";
            $btn.id = "player" + (i+1);
            $articles[i].after($btn);
        }
    }());
    
    // ---- Script end
});
```

```css
[class^='sibling'] {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="maincontent">
    
    <article class="siblings">Architecto minus, laboriosam vitae natus voluptatum debitis alias asperiores, voluptatibus repudiandae harum sed repellendus? Magni, possimus, ad! <em>Quam perspiciatis praesentium, excepturi mollitia.</em></article>
    
    <article class="siblings"><em>Ullam iusto praesentium minima, placeat nam, fugiat nulla suscipit impedit soluta, aliquid a eaque omnis perspiciatis animi officiis minus nesciunt nostrum quisquam?</em></article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
    <article class="siblings">Corporis neque sunt error quaerat, deserunt non suscipit quidem ducimus dolor libero. Laboriosam placeat minus, nobis explicabo consequatur aut culpa praesentium qui.</article>
    
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) since you're using its pal [`.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
function play(e) {
    var $article = $(this).prev();
    $article.html("played");
}
```

Usage:

```
$($btn).click(play);
```